# Поиск в сломанном массиве

Tags: python, алгоритм

**Выдает в двух тестах -1**

вот сама задача:
Алла ошиблась при копировании из одной структуры данных в другую. Она хранила массив чисел в кольцевом буфере. Массив был отсортирован по возрастанию, и в нём можно было найти элемент за логарифмическое время. Алла скопировала данные из кольцевого буфера в обычный массив, но сдвинула данные исходной отсортированной последовательности. Теперь массив не является отсортированным. Тем не менее, нужно обеспечить возможность находить в нем элемент за
O
(
log
n
)
.
Можно предполагать, что в массиве только уникальные элементы.

```
def broken_search(nums, target) -> int:
    start = 0
    end = len(nums) - 1
    mid = end // 2
    if end == 0:
        if nums[0] == target:
            return 0
        return -1
    while start < end - 1:
        left = nums[start]
        middle = nums[mid]
        if target == middle:
            return mid
        elif target < middle:
            if left >= target:
                return binary_search(nums, target, start, mid)
            end = mid
            mid = (start + end + 1) // 2
        else:
            if target <= nums[end]:
                return binary_search(nums, target, mid, end)
            start = mid
            mid = (start + end + 1) // 2
    return -1

def binary_search(nums, target, start, end) -> int:
    if start >= end:
        if nums[end] == target:
            return start
        return -1
    mid = (start + end) // 2
    if target == nums[mid]:
        return mid
    elif target < nums[mid]:
        return binary_search(nums, target, start, mid - 1)
    else:
        return binary_search(nums, target, mid + 1, end)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    array = [19,21,100,101,1,4,5,7,12]
    print(broken_search(array, 50))
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать! В чем собственно у вас вопрос?

Comment: Не могу понять где ошибка в коде

Comment: Возращает -1,  что ли? Неплохо было бы писать это в самом вопросе [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1306724/edit)

Comment: Простите, буду внимательней. Да возвращает -1, а должен вернуть индекс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил не разбираться в вашем коде, но предоставить альтернативное решение. Сначала была идея воспользоваться бинарным поиском для нахождения сдвига. Но потом реализовал вот так:

```py
def binary_search_for_broken(arr: list, search_value: int) -> int:
    start_value  = arr[0]
    start = 0
    end = len(arr) - 1
    while start <= end:
        middle = start + (end-start) // 2
        if search_value == arr[middle]:
            return middle
        if (arr[middle] < start_value) is not (search_value < start_value) or (arr[middle] > search_value):
            end = middle - 1
        else:
            start = middle + 1
    return -1

array = [19,21,100,101,1,4,5,7,12]
print(binary_search_for_broken(array, 1))
print(binary_search_for_broken(array, 50))
print(binary_search_for_broken(array, 12))
print(binary_search_for_broken(array, 101))
```

вывод соответственно

```
4
-1 # этого элемента в массиве не существует
8
3
```

Comment: попробуйте в списке [5, 1] найти единицу.

Comment: `is not` для логических выражений - это что вообще такое? )  Лучше в явном виде `!=` написать тогда уж, а так это не пойми что и непонятно как скобки работают в этом случае и куда `or` попадает опять же непонятно.

Comment: @CrazyElf в данном коде побольше проблем) вернусь как нибудь, переработаю=)